# City and State Picker for a specific Country

Tags: flutter, location

All of you must have seen those **Select Country**, **State** and **City** `Dropdown menus/ picker`.

I can't find a way to implement that in Flutter.

> Manually Adding data of all cities, states etc. is not possible.

Any Suggestion on how to do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm late to give answer, you can use https://pub.dev/packages?q=csc_picker
It has search facility and easy integration

Comment: Well, I used a JSON file since this package wasn't there then but nowthis will help others for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package: 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_country_picker

Or you can extract the list of countries from the package and create your own dropdown using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply! Tho I wanted a City picker.